# Select Element behind WAF Controller using Java/Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am having an issue with a Selenium WebDriver automation that I am writing. One of the pages I need to automate has a container of the following classes:

waf-application, waf-header and waf-toolbarlayout

My understanding is that WAF (Web Application Firewall??) is design to stop SQL injection etc. However for some reason, this WAF container is stopping me from selecting any elements on the page.

I have also tried using Selenium IDE.. and I can only select the top level WAF container, none of the elements below??

I can't really give an example because this is an internal server based application,and I would have no idea how to build such an application from scratch, but any advice would be appreciated!

```
private final static String LBL_QRY_XPATH = "//*[text()=\"Query:\"]";
private final static String BTN_SEARCH_XPATH = "//*[text()=\"Search Database\"]";

protected void waitForElementByXpath(String xpathOfElement) {

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpathOfElement)));

}

public long query() throws Exception{

    WebElement btnSearch = driver.findElement(By.xpath(BTN_SEARCH_XPATH));
    btnSearch.click();

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    this.waitForElementByXpath(LBL_QRY_XPATH);

    stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    return (stopTime - startTime);

}
```

The Exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 30 seconds waiting for presence of element located by: By.xpath: //*[text()="Query:"]
```

Thanks in advance,

Tim

Comment: At least give a piece of code or erroe you have?

Comment: Hello Mahsum I have edited the original post to include some code. Thank you for your help. I have written 100s of tests using this framework, for some reason I just cannot select anything on this particular page. I can only select the top level container.

Comment: Can you select or see elements manually?

Comment: I can select and see them using the cursor in the browser, however using WebDriver or Selenium IDE I cannot. It's like there is something overlaying them. Strangely all the other pages also have this parent container, but they work fine.

Comment: What do you see html code for an element?